# Can I figure out at compile time if a template specialization would eventually fail?

Tags: c++, templates, c++-concepts

Is it possible to figure out at compile time that a template specialization with the given parameters would produce a compile time error?

The following will fail at compile time. Is it possible to figure this out without knowing anything about std::find, and without actually getting the compile time error?

```
int a;
std::vector< std::vector <int> > v;     
std::vector< std::vector <int> >::iterator it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), a);
```

I assume that my program with or without the template specialization will either compile or fail in a finite time. Hopefully this avoids the Halting problem concern.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You're asking how to know at compile time that a compile error would happen -- well, that is discovered at compile time.  Please expand on your question and provide an example to illustrate what you're asking.  Maybe you're looking for `static_assert`?

Comment: No, that can surely be reduced to the halting problem.

Comment: It should be possible to determine this using SFINAE, with a generous sprinkle of `decltype()` and `std::declval`, but without something more concrete and actual code, nothing further can besaid.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik SFINAE cannot detect errors inside the function bodies, which is where `std::find` will fail.

Comment: In other order of things: `auto it = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), a);`

Comment: @Quimby no, not a priori. the Halting problem is a general aspect, mostly referred to self-referrencing entities of a problem. It doesn't state a priori, that a program cannot analyze (sub-) parts of its own in general. SFINAE is the best example, that works due to introduced cascades of analysis (via deduction context hierarchic distinction).

Comment: @Secundi Since templates themselves are Turing complete, isn't asking whether a (sub)program compiles same as asking whether the encoded program in the templates terminates? E.g. `compute<N>` could run the `N`-nth program( w.r.t some ordering) on input `N`. Sure, there could be limits in place, same as there are for templates. I was just trying to say that's not an easy problem.

Comment: @Quimby, yes, I just wanted to state, that it depends on the actual issue :) Now for the concrete presented code, we see, that it's a classical SFINAE issue.